# Centrifugal force acting on Spacecraft

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, orbital-motion

This Question may sound very naive. Still somebody can explain the basics in simple words. As I understand, when we equate the *centrifugal force* acting on spacecraft in *circular orbit* with *gravitational force*, we are not in an *inertial frame of reference*. But in popular available literature, all the results are worked out assuming an *inertial frame of reference*. But centrifugal force doesn't exist in an *inertial frame of reference*. So exactly how it can be explained.

Comment: @Andy thanks for providing the link. Its quite informative.

Comment: I posted this on a similar question but it is important if you wish to understand these things.  You should understand that the only force involved here is gravity and because it is unbalanced, an object in orbit would experience centripetal acceleration. One can stay in orbit because the force is conservative and mostly acts to change the orbiting objects velocity direction, not so much its speed (unless orbit is elliptical).  There is no such thing as _centripetal force_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither does "universal gravity" exist in inertial frame of reference.

Inertial frame of reference requires a zero sum of external forces. If the centrifugal force and gravity force cancel each other out, what remains is an inertial frame of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the process of equating ***centrifugal*** force with the force of gravity is not the process that is carried out.

Rather:

Assume that a body of mass $m$ is in a circular orbit with radius $r$ and velocity $v$.

The ***centripetal*** force **needed** to maintain this circular orbit , $F_{cp}$, is given by:$$F_{cp}=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$Further assuming that the body is in orbit around a primary with mass $M$, the force of gravity **available** at this orbit distance,$F_g$ is given by:$$F_g=G\frac{mM}{r^2}$$Equating these produces the normal equation for circular orbits.

This equation can be simplified:  for example, $G$ and $M$ can be replaced by a combination of the surface gravity, $g_s$ and the primary radius, $R$.

Note that different circular orbits are possible.  For example, an orbiting craft that is willing and able to thrust continuously could orbit at a much higher speed by using thrust to augment gravity to supply the greater centripetal force needed...

Comment: of course in case of such a craft it would not be an inertial frame of reference. It's because gravity provides the same force against all objects in the orbiting craft (plus the craft itself) that the craft's frame of reference is inertial.